# What font does Frank & Oak use?

Tags: font-identification

I find [Frank & Oak's font](http://www.frankandoak.com/) simple and beautiful. Could someone please tell me what font this is?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The one used in the titles is [DINCondB](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/fontfont/ff-din/cond-bold/), did you try [WhatTheFont](http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/) for the logo?

[image]

Comment: WhatTheFont isn't even necessary, you can view the source and search the stylesheets for `@font` since they are using it as a web font in this case

Comment: It's all DIN or, for some of the smaller stuff, Georgia or it's fallbacks.